# Google+ Login doesn't keep logged in

Tags: google-plus

I'm new in this google+ log in system, but I finally made my google+ and facebook log in buttons which are almost fully functioning except for one problem - When I clock on login with google+ small window pops out(which should be conditions) and fades instantly, after that I am logged in, though if I reload page or go to other link it logs me out.
The code:

```
<script>
    function signinCallback(authResult)
    {
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in'])
        {
            $("#header_right_info").html('<a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href" id="log_out" onclick="gapi.auth.signOut();">Log out G</a>');
            $("#login_with").css("display", "none");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
    }
</script>
```

console says: "Sign-in state: user_signed_out"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function()
    {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I think this can happen if you do not include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` in the Google+ authentication SCOPE.

Comment: No,I've got it included: 
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"